# Why can't i save a string in char array?

Tags: c, arrays

```
//pick() returns a random word.
char* randomWord = pick(); //save random word in randomWord var
int length = strlen(randomWord); //get length of the randomWord
char HiddenRandomWord[length];
char* stringHiddenRandomWord = HiddenRandomWord;

for (i = 0; i<=length; i++){
     HiddenRandomWord[i] = '_';
     if (i == length) HiddenRandomWord[i] = '\0';
}

printf("%s", stringHiddenRandomWord);
```

I just want to save in an array: `_ _ _ _ _ //every letter is one low bar`

If the length of the random word, for example, is 7, the output would be: _______ // 7 times _

But if I moidfy `HiddenRandomWord[i] = ' _';` //notice the space added before the low bar, the output it keeps being `_______`, it justs takes the last character.

I know that when it has simple quotes it's for only one character and for double quotes it's for more than one character. I have triend all the ways and I don't get it.

Comment: We don't know what `pick` is or do. You probably want to use [strcpy(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) or perhaps [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) and you should read a good book about C programming. Don't forget to compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: `' _'` is neither a valid c-string the way you think it is, nor a single char - you can't copy it like that.

Comment: pick() just get a random word from an array and it returns it

Comment: note that `strlen` does not count the final `'\0'`, so you would need one more character for `HiddenRandomWord` (especially since you actually write at that index).

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. If, for each input character in `RandomWord`, you want to put two characters in `HiddenRandomWord`, just do that: `HiddenRandomWord[2*i] = ' '; HiddenRandomWord[2*i+1] = '_';` (you need twice as many characters in HiddenRandomWord obviously, and don't forget the terminating `'\0'`). Why you would need to create `HiddenRandomWord` like that is somewhat a mystery to me, but you can.

Comment: But how does `pick` work? If *you* wrote it, it is likely to be as buggy as the rest of your code ... :-(

Comment: pick() method -> http://pastebin.com/ktjUwvqp

Comment: rand()%9 should be 3 and words[3], i know, i actually have a longer array

Comment: You are returning a pointer to a local variable `word`. Basically `randomWord` is pointing to garbage. Secondly *rand()%9* returns 0-8, but *word[]* has only 3 words assigned!

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
char HiddenRandomWord[length];
```

should be

```
char HiddenRandomWord[length+1];
```

Which also means this statement is writing outside the array

```
if (i == length) HiddenRandomWord[i] = '\0';
```

So your loop should be

```
for (i = 0; i<length; i++) {
    HiddenRandomWord[i] = '_';
    }
```

Followed by

```
HiddenRandomWord[i] = 0 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the memset () function in that fashion, and you have no use of stringHiddenRandomword :

```
char* randomWord = pick();
char* HiddenRandomWord = malloc(strlen(randomWord) + 1);
if (HiddenRandomWord == NULL) perror("malloc");
memset(HiddenRandomWord, '_', strlen(randomWord)); 

printf("%s//%d\n", HiddenRandomWord, strlen(hiddenRandomWord);
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: you dont understand it. if random word is for example, hello, output must be _ _ _ _ _ //5 _ because hello has 5 letters